# How to avoid "Received: (from root@localhost)" when sending mails from sendmail function?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, sendmail

It passes both SPF and DKIM, but Gmail still marks it as spam.
I noticed that there is something like this in the email headers:

`Received: (from root@localhost) by mydomain.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id v0R4tOqT009065; Fri, 27 Jan 2017 04:55:24 GMT`

This happens when I send the mail in the command-line.  If it's sent by PHP when someone visits the website, it changes to `from www-data@localhost`

How can I change it to the actual sender address?
Here's the full header:

```
Delivered-To: xxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.12.176.77 with SMTP id l13csp74374qvc;
        Thu, 26 Jan 2017 20:55:28 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.99.101.193 with SMTP id z184mr7291389pgb.216.1485492928174;
        Thu, 26 Jan 2017 20:55:28 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <root@mydomain.com>
Received: from mydomain.com (mydomain.com. [45.76.111.24])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 20si3316577pfu.287.2017.01.26.20.55.27
        for <xxx@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 26 Jan 2017 20:55:27 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of root@mydomain.com designates 45.76.111.24 as permitted sender) client-ip=45.76.111.24;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of root@mydomain.com designates 45.76.111.24 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@mydomain.com
Received: from mydomain.com (mydomain.com [45.76.111.24]) by mydomain.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-4) with ESMTP id v0R4tO19009066 for <    xxx@gmail.com>; Fri, 27 Jan 2017 04:55:25 GMT
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=mydomain.com; s=default; t=1485492925; bh=ftnjnh4sfzHQMJKMVUjQsNdbl/+WlV83iWkmffs8/  Bs=; h=Date:To:Subject:From:From; b=mQavJF62btZ7izrNljK+P0alo4vZMOi2hcDo7I0kW+XmlP+uxGEXEfxaX8nYxY9KX
     SOvibSqC62F+BUeVLeWyBp8qAFtN3/uvTxQNif83ZAYny/KNlhBDo3VcCq2XrY8lj7
     ERI+nUknfaSCP1Z3m/F2M7YxBRlXhQEnSqSeDI/Q=
Received: (from root@localhost) by mydomain.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id v0R4tOqT009065; Fri, 27 Jan 2017 04:55:24 GMT
Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2017 04:55:24 GMT
Message-Id: <201701270455.v0R4tOqT009065@mydomain.com>
To: xxx@gmail.com
Subject: test email
From: noreply@mydomain.com
```

In `/etc/hosts` I have:

```
45.76.111.24    mydomain.com mydomain.com
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain
127.0.1.1       guest
```

Where mydomain.com is also my hostname.

Comment: Just a thought, but have you added `mydomain.com` to the `127.0.0.1` entry in your hosts file? eg
`127.0.0.1    mydomain.com localhost localhost.localdomain`

Comment: This might help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/725792/how-to-remove-received-from-apachelocalhost-and-sendmail-version-from-header

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/hostname`, what do you see there?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the "From" smtp header in your Php code. If you are using the Php mail function then see the "additional headers" parameter for the Php mail function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Your email headers do not show any problems. You can try to move the email from your SPAM folder to your inbox manually.